# How to remove top padding for text in UITextView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, text, padding

I have a unusual problem. First i have Nav Controller and as a one page i have view controller with top panel for back button. I added uiview and uitextview on it. Then i make all needed constraints and after run and see top padding for text in textview about ~60 px . And i dont really know how to remove it.

1. I tried:

   ```
   textViewUserInput.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-50, 5, 5, 5);
   ```

   it works but value -50 for top inset is not good for different devices and orientation
2. I also tried:

   ```
   textViewUserInput.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
   textViewUserInput.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
   ```

   doesn't change anything

Comment: screenshot [look here](http://i003.radikal.ru/1508/6f/2dc05810fe9b.jpg)

Comment: What‘s constraints did you add?

Answer (score 8):

In Main.storyboard, select your view controller the one that has the UITextView in and underneath your attributes inspector tab uncheck "Adjust scroll view insets". I had the same problem and that worked for me.

Comment: This is the exact solution to the problem (XCode7 / swift 2.x) for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add `[textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero]; or textView.textContainerInset = .zero` in your code.